# Do I have to recheck posted data on server if I use html 5 validation?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Im making a simple form template for wordpress. I have written:

```
<form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="productForm" method="post">

    <table>

        <tr>
            <td>Address:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="address" required="required" placeholder="Enter place"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td><input type="email" name="email" required="required" placeholder="Enter email"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Size:</td>
            <td><input type="number" size="3" placeholder="x" name="x-size" required="required" min="1">
                <input type="number" size="3" placeholder="y" name="y-size" required="required" min="1">
                <input type="number" size="3" placeholder="z" name="z-size" required="required" min="1">cm
            </td>
        </tr>

   </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true">
    <button type="submit" value="submitted">Submit</button>
</form>
```

It checks every value I need, but should I recheck it on the server with php for security?

Comment: What do you think happens when my user agent doesn't support your fancy html5 checks? What happens when I post data without any browser at all?

Comment: What happens when Malicious Malcolm saves your HTML to disk, rips out the validation, loads the HTML from disk, and sends you SQL injection, XSS, CSRF, drinks your beer, steals your girlfriend, and leaves dirty socks on the pillow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to check it server side. Client side validation can add some design to your site, however anything client side can be easily manipulated by the user. Making sure to validate and sanitize any data you plan on storing into the data base is always a good idea.

You can find information on this at http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-build-your-own-wordpress-contact-form-and-why/ Just scroll down to the validation and for sanitation visit http://devotepress.com/wordpress-coding/data-validation-and-sanitization-wordpress/#.VE1TAvnF-LU

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should always recheck server side as any client-side verification could be removed by anyone.

Comment: But should I recheck it like - if ( isset($_POST['x-size']) or simple if it is a number?

Comment: If you're using it for performing any type of logic or you have any kinds of restrictions on what you will be expecting the variable to be then yes validate it.

Answer (score 1):

Client side validation is for better user experience while server side is for security & reliability as client side validations can be by-passed by end users.

Answer (score 0):

You should always validate data on server side. Client-side validation is not reliable. Reliable as in "it can be tampered with".